# How load a local WebView in Nativescript/ vue JS

Tags: html, vue.js, webview, nativescript

I would like to display a local files (html+css) for that I use NativeScript with Vue JS

My code is :

Call of html file ( path: App/html/Fleur.html)

I have see different topic like this but I don't understand how that work.

```
<template>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="home-panel">
                <WebView height="1200px" src="~/html/Fleur.html" />
                <!--Add your page content here-->
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</template>

<script>
import html from "~/html/Fleur.html";
    export default {
        data() {
            return {};
        }
    };
</script>
```

And my Web page is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Arya V</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="landing" id="landing">

      <ul class="landing__iconsList absolute" id="iconsList"></ul>

      <div class="landing__stat absolute">
        <div id="app"></div>

        <div class="landing__shape goal absolute" id="goal"></div>
        <div class="landing__shape currentweek absolute" id="currentweek"></div>
        <div class="landing__shape lastweek absolute" id="lastweek"></div>

        <div class="landing__focus absolute">
          <div class="landing__focus__completion absolute"></div>
          <div class="landing__focus__main absolute">
            <img class="landing__focus__main__icon" src="images/energy.svg"></img>
            <p class="landing__focus__main__description">Énergie</p>
            <p class="landing__focus__main__value">65</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>

    <script src="data.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import the HTML page, no use for this.

Have to follow this approach, [official docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/web-view)

with importing the webview components, the observable, using the args.object to get hold of the view and set it up etc.

Alternatively, you can use a plugin like [webview plugin](https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-webview-ext)

which allow you to do more than the native one.